# Get thumbnail images for Fusion 360 file with autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to get the URL of a thumbnail image for a Fusion 360 CAD file to display on my platform. Is this possible with forge? I have dug through the items and haven't seen anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the URN of your Fusion file already, you can access the Thumbnail with [the GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/thumbnail API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-thumbnail-GET/). If this API returns you a 4040 error, you might need to call [the POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) first, with Thumbnail options.

Comment: This is strange to me and I thought that I was misunderstanding it. To get a thumbnail, we have to convert the URN to something else, send a post to translate the file into some other kind of file, and then send a get command for the thumbnail? Are we actually retrieving that thumbnail or are we getting a URL? I couldn't find an example where the full process of getting a thumbnail was carried out. What format must the file be translated into?

Comment: See details about converting to thumbnails here: https://docdro.id/X21kcSN